# How can I use SVM in Java

Tags: java, weka, svm

I'm extremally new to SVM. I need to extract sentences from text and I have found an article that explains how to do it by using SVM algorithm.
How can I implement SVM in Java? Is it correct to use Weka to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Weka. You can also use SVM directly from **LibSVM** (which Weka actually wraps).

Comment: Thank you. Which one is better?

Comment: I prefer Weka wrapper, since it provides much more algorithm in addition to SVM. Though, free version of Weka is GPL'ed, so you cannot use it in commercial software for free. LibSVM is BSD licensed, so it doesn't have such limitations.

Answer (score 0):

FYI : Platt's SMO,Sequential Minimal Optimization is implemented in WEKA itself, which you can use too.